# How to extract out elapsedTime attribute values from file

Tags: text-processing, json

I wish to extracted out elapsedTime attribute values from the file.

Records look

```
{"realm":"/test","transactionId":"9e26c614","elapsedTime":17,"elapsedTimeUnits":"MILLISECONDS","_id":"9e26c6asdasd"}
```

The file I am having is in gb's and I want to get the values greater than 10000.

I tried to grep but due to colon grep is not working.

```
grep -wo --color 'elapsedTime' fileName -> this just prints attribute names
grep -w  --color "elapsedTime" fileName -> this just highlights the attribute.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data is JSON format so it's best to use a parser that understands this format.

This will pick out the `elapsedTime` value from the JSON in the file `/tmp/data`

```
jq .elapsedTime /tmp/data
17
```

This will pick out only those values larger than 10000

```
jq '.elapsedTime | select(. > 10000)' /tmp/data
```

If you really cannot use `jq` then a `sed|awk` construct can be considered. However, this requires that there must be only one `elapsedTime` label and associated value per line. There may be other caveats and I really do not recommend it, but if you're desperate here it is,

```
sed -En 's/^.*"elapsedTime":\s*"?([0-9]+).*$/\1/p' /tmp/data |
    awk '$1 > 10000'
```

In response to a follow-up question ([comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672771/how-to-extract-out-elapsedtime-attribute-values-from-file/672773?noredirect=1#comment1269420_672773)), to pick out two elements you need to filter on a single element from the object, and then display the required elements:

```
jq -r 'select (.elapsedTime > 10000) | [ .elapsedTime, .transactionId ] | @tsv ' /tmp/data
```

Answer (score 1):

If `jq` not available, `sed` can be used.

```
ELAP=$(sed 's/.*"elapsedTime":\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' filename)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfT0spNSexoDg1JSQzN1XJKkYj2kDXMlYrRlNPSz/GUJ/r//9qpaLUxJxcJSsl/ZLU4hIlHaWSosS84sTkksz8PM8UoLhlqpFZspmhCVAKxTBDcxSB0LzMkmKgcl9PHx/PYFdnfz@XYKCW@EyEGYnFKUCkVAsA)